# List ID & Custom Field Not Pulling Into SendGrid via Zapier

Tags: json, sendgrid, zapier

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

I am a marketer by trait, with some technical skills, but not a developer by nature; so I wanted to reach out to a developer community to help me. I am currently setting up a process to run a pre-launch email referral campaign through viral loops (https://viral-loops.com/templates/startup-prelaunch) and am using Zapier to connect it to the ESP we are using, SendGrid, since there is no direct integration.

I am trying to pass over the following information

- First Name
- Last Name
- Participant URL (the URL the user can share to refer people)
- Added to a specific list (Early Access Waitlist)

I have set up the zap successfully so that it is passing through the first name, last name, and adding contacts to our ESP. However, I cannot figure out, why I cannot get it to add to the specific audience list or add the participant URL.

For the list id, I thought I have followed this step properly -- https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact#body

For the participant URL, I created a custom field in SendGrid and then use the above doc. and thought it should pull in.

I have attached the current Zap setup in this link:

[image: Update after hopscotch]

Thanks in advance for the help!

[image: Zapier Error Message]

[image: Zapier Trouble Shoot Details]

[image: Hopscotch JSON Error]

Answer (score 0):

A few things here, the shape of your JSON isn't exactly right, I'll show you that in a bit. Your `participant_URL` field is a custom field, so it needs to go in the `custom_fields` property of a contact and use the ID of the custom field. And your list IDs should be IDs and not names.

For the custom field ID, the easiest way to get the ID is by calling [the API to get the field definitions](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/custom-fields/get-all-field-definitions). You could likely do this with another Zap to the API. Or the following `curl` command in your terminal:

```
curl -X GET https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/field_definitions \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>>"
```

The List ID is easier to get. Just go to your lists in the Marketing Campaigns section of the SendGrid dashboard and click on the list. The ID is in the URL: `https://mc.sendgrid.com/contacts/lists/<<YOUR_LIST_ID>>`.

For the JSON, it should look like this:

```json
{
  "list_ids": ["YOUR_LIST_ID"],
  "contacts": [{
    "email": "email@example.com",
    "first_name": "Alice",
    "last_name": "Franks",
    "custom_fields": [{
      "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID_FOR_URL": "https://vrips.co/XXXXX"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Hey Phil, I appreciate the response, the list ID makes sense, I went ahead and made changes to my best understanding. I updated the image in the original question section to my current setup in Zapier, where I am now getting an error for "Invalid JSON". Can you take a look and see where I am still going wrong there? Thanks. Additionally, for the custom field ID, can you explain where I need to put the "curl command in your terminal". Also, apologize if this response is not super clear, I am having trouble adding images or formatting anything in this comments section.

Comment: Updating the question is totally fine, just make sure to comment like you have to let me know there is a change. You have invalid JSON because you need to surround the list id with quotes and the should be a comma between that list and "contacts". Like `"list_ids": ["dffbbddd-707e-823e-7c191404eb2c"],`. Take a look at how my JSON is formatted in the answer to see any differences.

Comment: Rather than using `curl` maybe you could use [Hoppscotch](https://hoppscotch.io/). Enter the URL (`https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/field_definitions`) next to where it says `GET`, then in the Authorization tab below change the type to "Bearer" and enter your API key where it says "Token". Press _Send_ and the JSON response should be returned below. You should see the `custom_fields`, which will be a list of objects showing the name and also the ID that you need.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the Zap image in the original question above. I corrected the errors in the JSON as you described and then ran it through a JSON validator, so that is fixed. Then hopscotch worked great, and I got the ID as needed. Now I am running into an error "Invalid Input". This makes me think the custom field cannot take in a URL? The options SendGrid gives me are Text, Number, and Date; I currently have it set up as text.

Comment: The URL is just text though, so that shouldn't be a problem. Can you see the full response from SendGrid? Normally an error response will include more information in the body of the response. If you can't get that information from Zapier, using Hoppscotch to try out the requests should show you more too.

Comment: There is no response on the SendGrid side, just in the Zapier platform, however, it is not too specific. I have reached out to both SendGrid and Zapier support, and they tell me to reach out to the other sides' support. How would I test it in Hoppscotch?

Comment: I uploaded an image in the original question to show what I see from Zapier's side regarding error messages. It must be about the custom fields section since when I remove that part, the test of the Zap provides no error messages.

Comment: Is the Zap making a `PUT` request to the SendGrid API? You should also be able to test this in Hoppscotch using the URL `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts`, setting it to make a `PUT` request and copying the raw JSON (should look like the JSON in my answer above) into the body of the request, and making sure you have the auth set the same as when you made the request to the custom fields endpoint.

Comment: Ok, I ran that through hopscotch and attached the error it shows me. It says the same as Zapier; "Invalid Input". I am not sure how to adjust for the error based on this in Hopscotch.

Comment: Does that error mean I need to add a section in the JSON about field_type? From this API call -- https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/custom-fields/create-custom-field-definition

Comment: I don't think so, can you try making the request with Hoppscotch but without the custom fields for now?